# how Ripple Xcurrent works?

Tags: ripple, ripple-api

As per my knowledge **Xcurrent uses blockchain**. But how it uses **blockchain** ? **Xcurrent or Interledger protocol talk about ledger entries**, I would like to know, do they really use **blockchain** as a ledgers in **bank transfer** or they use banks **native ledgers like (databases or anything)**? What is difference between **general** and **sub-ledger**?, is **sub-ledger** is referred as bank's **native ledger** ?

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at the "How it works" document on their website, the first time they mention the word "Blockchain" is in their "About the company" section in the end of the document. So I would be quite sure that their product has absolutely nothing to do with any kind of blockchain technology.

Comment: so it means that they are using pure messaging layer with Xcurrent, nothing else related to blockchain? and they ledgers are databases kinda things??

Comment: xCurrent has the same problem that blockchains like bitcoin have. You have parties that don't trust each other and are not willing to trust any single central authority, yet you need them to reliably agree on whether or not a payment took place.